# Adding a current project to SVN but ignoring certain file types

Tags: linux, svn, ignore

I currently have a project which I want to add to SVN but I don't want to version certain file types. (e.g. .png) or a folder (images).

I know there's the svn:ignore, but this will not work if there's no .svn file in the directory which I'm trying to perform the ignore operation. I get the following errors :

```
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
svn: 'common' is not under version control
```

I'm looking for someone to inform me as to how to do this or direct me in the right place.

Any time I'm trying this, its like I have to add the file/directory to svn using 'svn add' and then run the ignore. I've a lot of directories and I'm looking to do this recursively also.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: In linux you could easily use a bash script (or any number of other scripts) to recursively perform a command, for example by doing `find . -type d -exec "<command here> {} denotes where to place directory"`. Regarding setting the property failing, have you tried being in the parent and setting svn:ignore on the directory from there?

Comment: HI, yes. I've added the repository to svn. just an empty repository. I check it out. so the parent directory contains the .svn file. I pull in my project and if I run
`svn propset svn:ignore -F ignore_files . --recursive`
it will only ignore files from the top directory. It does not filter down to the sub directories.

Comment: Try `svn propset -R svn:ignore directory-to-ignore`. I'm not sure you need that to be recursive though, do you?

Comment: I think I do need to be recursive yeah. I need the ignore to filter down through the subdirectories.

If I ran `svn propset svn:ignore '*.png' .` from the top directory, png's from sub directories still get added and commited.

when I run that command I get the second error from above
`svn: 'common' is not under version control`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know then. I've never really bothered with svn:ignore as I mostly deal with svn via subclipse.

Comment: Ok, no bother. I have svn subclipse too. I might try it on that and see if it works. But I was looking to do it via command line. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `global-ignores` in Subversion configuration file (normally found on Linux at `~/.subversion/config`). See the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2) for more info.